# Only first and last GTK3 Combo Box Entry Working

Tags: c, if-statement, combobox, switch-statement, gtk3

I use C switch based on a variable I set according to which GTK Combo Box Text entry is selected ( variable = 3 <===>  case 3: ... etc. ). There are 4 entries. My trouble is getting the 2nd and 3rd entries to actually do something.

Only the first and last entries seem to carry the variable value properly.

I have tested it repeatedly, seeing if I need to use if/else rather than a switch, to no avail. It is probably more than a coincidence, though, that the middle two entries are ignored in the program. Right now, I am using 4 if/else statements. There is the same behaviour, however, with switch (only the first and last entries cause the program to do something, which, in my case, is cause a dialog box to show and then, upon clicking, launch a terminal window showing progress).

Please, please, help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I am using GTK3.

EDIT: I am now posting the relevant parts of my code below:

```
int gaming = 0;
int websurf = 1;
int netwman = 2;
int compmaint = 3;
int selected;
```

Here (just above), constants and the variable to be compared with ("selected"), are declared. Then, for the character strings gotten through gtk_combo_box_text_get_active() later, character strings are declared as follows:

```
const char *str1[];
const char *str2[];
const char *str3[];
const char *str4[];
```

Here (just below), initiateWrite() is defined at compile-time. All of these so far are at compile-time. This is where I have been trying to use if/else or switch so that I can have action based on EACH of the GTK Combo Box Text entries. Only the FIRST and LAST entries actually do something.

```
void initiateWrite() {

if (selected == gaming) {
    system(SCRIPT1);
} else

if (selected == websurf) {
    system(SCRIPT2);
} else

if (selected == netwman) {
    system(SCRIPT3);
} else

if (selected == compmaint) {
    system(SCRIPT4);
} 

else return;

}
```

Where SCRIPT1 through SCRIPT4 are defined at compile-time like so:

```
#define SCRIPT1 "\
#/bin/bash \n\
xterm -e \"sudo bash gaming /dev/sdc1\"\n\
"
```

The program is supposed to detect a medium inserted in USB port (thumb drive), and yes, thumb drives have always been inserted during my testing (just in case of questions).

I also have been using if/else or switch later on in my code, which could also be causing the issue. Here:

```
void setSelected(GtkWidget *cbox_text, gpointer data) {
    const char *selectionString = gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(
            cbox_text);
    strcpy(str1, "Gaming");
    strcpy(str2, "Web Surfing/Remote File Transfer");
    strcpy(str3, "Network Management");
    strcpy(str4, "Computer Maintenance");

    if (strcmp(selectionString, str1) == 0) {
        selected = gaming;
    } else

    if (strcmp(selectionString, str2) == 0) {
        selected = websurf;
    } else

    if (strcmp(selectionString, str3) == 0) {
        selected = netwman;
    } else

    if (strcmp(selectionString, str4) == 0) {
        selected = compmaint;
    } else return;
}
```

I don't know whether changing the selectionString to a "gchar" will help fix the issue. Doing a cast to (const char*) as I've previously done has caused some pretty strange behavior (crashes). I'm also not sure how to implement the "gchar" if that's the required solution.

Thanks again

Comment: It's impossible to know what is wrong with your code without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Posted code just now.

Comment: Why are you `strcpy()`ing the strings to apparently global variables, that looks like a bad solution for whatever you are trying to do, have you tried `strcmp(selectionString, "Gaming") == 0`?

Comment: You should also consider using the `udisk` safe api instead of bash scripts.

Comment: OMG thank you for your wise words. It works now.